# Evaluate the goodness of a distributional fits

Tags: scipy, distribution, scipy.stats

I have fitted some distributions for sample data with the following code:

```
import numpy as np 
import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

samp = norm.rvs(loc=0,scale=1,size=150) # (example) sample values. 

figprops = dict(figsize=(8., 7. / 1.618), dpi=128)                       
adjustprops = dict(left=0.1, bottom=0.1, right=0.97, top=0.93, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2)

import pylab
fig = pylab.figure(**figprops)                                            
fig.subplots_adjust(**adjustprops)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)  
ax.hist(samp,bins=10,density=True,alpha=0.6,color='grey', label='Data')
xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()

# Distributions. 
import scipy.stats
dist_names = ['beta', 'norm','gumbel_l'] 
for dist_name in dist_names:
    dist = getattr(scipy.stats, dist_name)
    param = dist.fit(samp)
    x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100) # 
    ax.plot(x,dist(*param).pdf(x),linewidth=4,label=dist_name)

ax.legend(fontsize=14)
plt.savefig('example.png')
```

How do I order the distribution names in  the legend from best fit (top) to worst fit automatically? I have generated in a loop random variables, the result of the best fit may be different each iteration.

Comment: since this post, have you resorted to a different test for goodness-of-fit, or are you still using the KS test and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could use Kolmogorov-Smirnov (K-S) test to compute, f.e., p-value and sort by it

Modifying your loop

```
for dist_name in dist_names:
    dist = getattr(scipy.stats, dist_name)
    param = dist.fit(samp)
    x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100) # 
    ax.plot(x,dist(*param).pdf(x),linewidth=4,label=dist_name)

    ks = scipy.stats.kstest(samp, dist_name, args=param)
    print((dist_name, ks))
```

You could get as output something like

```
('beta', KstestResult(statistic=0.033975289251035434, pvalue=0.9951529119440156))
('norm', KstestResult(statistic=0.03164417055025992, pvalue=0.9982475331007705))
('gumbel_l', KstestResult(statistic=0.113229070386386, pvalue=0.039394595923043355))
```

which tells you normal and beta are pretty good, but gumbel should be last. Sorting based on either P-value or statistics should be easy to add

Your result might be different and would depend on RNG initial state.

UPDATE

Concerning non-applicability of the K-S test for goodness-of-fit estimate, I strongly disagree. I don't see scientific reason NOT to use it, and I used it myself for good.

Typically, you have black box generating your random data, let's say some measurements of network delays

In general, it could be described by mixture of Gammas, and you do your fit using some kind of quadratic utility function and get back set of parameters

Then you use K-S or any other empirical vs theoretical distribution method to estimate how good fit is. If K-S method is not used to make a fit, then it is perfectly good approach to use K-S.

You basically have one black box generating data, another black box fitting data, and want to know how well fit fits the data. Then K-S will do the job.

And statement  "it is commonly used as a test for normality to see if your data is normally distributed." is completely off, in my humble opinion. K-S is about CDF-vs-CDF maximum discrepancy, and it doesn't care about normalcy, it is a lot more universal

Comment: On https://www.statisticshowto.com/kolmogorov-smirnov-test/ I saw that the 
limitations of the KS-test are: "In order for the test to work, you must specify the location, scale, and shape parameters. If these parameters are estimated from the data, it invalidates the test. If you don’t know these parameters, you may want to run a less formal test (like the one outlined in the empirical distribution function article).". Also, it says: "it is commonly used as a test for normality to see if your data is normally distributed." I would be more interested in a RMSE method based on the histogram.

Comment: @Jeroen added note wrt applicability of the K-S test

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am considering the K-S test now. Why would someone use the KS-test and not use RMSE method to validate the goodness of a fit?

Comment: Does `dist.fit(samp)` actively search (amongst all combinations of parameter settings) for the best fitting parameters for the best fitting parametric distribution. If so, how?

Comment: @develarist Yes and no. Yes, for particular distribution it will search best fitted parameters. No, you have to specify distributions names (list of them) in advance. Like in original question `dist_names = ['beta', 'norm','gumbel_l'] ` and code will try to fit three distributions and find best one using some  tests (Kolmogorov-Smirnov in this case)

Comment: yes i know that you have to feed a distribution family, but my question was, if I already know which distribution would fit the best, but just don't know how to parameterize that distribution, and I feed in only that *one single* distribution name, for example `norm`, then `dist.fit(samp)` will run through all possible combinations of parameters settings for that single distribution name in order to find the best fitting parameter set? or how does it work

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux nevermind, I found the answer. it uses MLE (maximum likelihood estimation) to find best parameters https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux In the code, the matching distribution is generated with `dist(*param).pdf(x)`. How can I back out the source data for this `dist(*param).pdf(x)`? i.e. go from distribution to dataset?

Comment: @develarist Yes, distribution PDF curve is generated by `dist(*param).pdf(x)` and plotted. If you want to sample from fitted distribution, I believe you should use `dist(*param).rvs(size=1000)` and you supposed to get 1000 random samples.