# How to find the best fitting parametric distribution for an empirical dataset (stock returns)?

Tags: python, scipy, distribution, finance, quantitative-finance

Given some real-valued empirical data (time series), I could convert it to a histogram to have an (non-parametric) **empirical distribution** of the data, but **histograms** are blocky and jagged.

Instead, I would like to identify the best-fitting **parametric distribution** from the `scipy` or `scipy.stats` libraries of distribution functions, so that I can artificially generate a parametric distribution that closely fits the empirical distribution of my real data.

If the empirical data are monthly returns of empirical AAPL stock returns, for example, I know that the parametric **Johnson-SU distribution** resembles, and can mimic, stock return distributions because of its customizable skew. However, the Johnson SU distribution in `scipy` requires four input parameters to be calibrated. How can I search for the best parameter settings of this parametric distribution from `scipy` that fits to the empirical distribution of my sample of AAPL returns?

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61276051/evaluate-the-goodness-of-a-distributional-fits/61292712#61292712) ?

Comment: Did you make any progress wrt the fit? Maybe you could post piece of your data on drop box (G drive or one drive) and share the link?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux using your code in the link, I tried to verify if the mean and variances match for the empirical data and the fitted parametric distribution, but they don't match and are quite different, despite the appearance of matching. is there something that explains why moments won't match?

Comment: It is hard to find source of the differences not seeing input and fit. Some outliers? Perhaps tails are getting different and make integrals (for moments) disagree?

Comment: not necessarily knocking the code, this is more of a shock. isn't the whole point of fitting an empirical distribution with a parametric distribution is that it resembles it as closely as possible? If the shape of the density alone is being given the pass, and no one checks to see if the statistical moments of the empirical and fitted distributions match, then a huge mistake is being made

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"I would like to identify the best-fitting parametric distribution from the `scipy` or `scipy.stats` libraries of distribution functions, so that I can artificially generate a parametric distribution that closely fits the empirical distribution of my real data."*

The link from [@SeverinPappadeux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4044696/severin-pappadeux) above might help ( K-S tests are fine ) yet it serves well but for the *analytical comparison* of a pair of already complete distribution, not for the process of the actual constructive generation thereof.

So let's disambiguate the goal:
- is the task focused on using `scipy` / `scipy.stats` generators?
or
- is the task focused on achieving a process of generating a synthetic distributions well-enough matching the empirical "original"?

---

**Should the former is your wish,**
then
we run into an oxymoron, to seek a parametrise-able (scripted) distribution generator-engine, that will (in some sense of a *"best"*-ness) match a principally un-scriptable empirical distribution
well, as one *might* still wish to do so
then
you will indeed end up in some sort of a painful ParameterSPACE search strategy (using the ready-made or customised `scipy`/`scipy.stats` hardcoded-generators) that will try to find the "best"-matching values of the ParameterSPACE-vector of these generators' hard-coded parameters. This may teach you to some degree about the sin of growing dimensionality ( the more parameters a hard-coded generator has, the larger is the ParameterSPACE search-space, going into **`O( n * i^N * f^M * c^P * b^Q)`** double trouble, having `N`-integer, `M`-float, `P`-cardinal and `Q`-boolean parameters of a respective hard-coded generator, which goes pretty nasty against your time-budget, doesn't it? ).

---

**Should the latter is the case,**
then
we may focus on a more productive way by proper defining what is the "wellness"-of-"matching" the *"original"*.

The first candidate for this is to generate a pretty random ( quite easily a PRNG-produced ) noise, that if not too "strong" inside the PriceDOMAIN direction may be simply added to the empirical-*"original"* & here we go.

More sophistication might be added, using the same trick of using superposition, drop-out(s), frequency-specific tricks, outlier add-on(s) (if later testing properties/limits of robustness of some dataflow-responsive strategies et al)

Anyway, all these methods for the latter target have a lovely property of not going anywhere wild into any vast searches of high-dimensionality ParameterSPACEs, but are often as nice as just `O( n )`-scaled -- that's cool, isn't it?

So, just one's own **imagination** is the limit here :o)

Comment: given empirical data that requires a continuous mold (best-fitting parametric distribution), i would have to say the latter case, even though this in turn requires the *implementation* of the former case (they are complementary actions). but your answer to the latter case is not instructive as to what I should implement, and is merely philosophy. what is PRNG, PriceDOMAIN, ParameterSPACEs? Can you be more specific about why "superposition, drop-out(s), frequency-specific tricks" have anything to do with the simple act of finding goodness-of-fit?

Comment: Negative, madam, the latter ( superposition ) strategy is being used for ages, so I would dare call it ***"not implementable"***. What is PRNG? Kindly see available Pseudo Random Number Generation theory ( what makes one PRNG better than other is more important for cryptography than for Quant-Fin ) What is PriceDOMAIN? Kindly notice there are phenomena in 2D (orthogonal) directions in the Quant-Fin Domain of Expertise, the PriceDOMAIN and the TimeDOMAIN, aren't they? What is ParameterSPACE? Kindly imagine that any Fun( a,b,c ) has a 3D-ParameterSPACE and similarly Fun( a,b,c,d ) 4D & so forth

Comment: Sorry, you have changed the text of your comment twice since posted, rendering my answer in the comment detached from your claims that were present in the ( now hidden ) original comment. This leads nowhere. I reserve the right not to follow a side-ways creeping topic. I could spend ages in reacting to another and another and another change of the subject.

Comment: i didn't say that the latter case is not implementable. I am asking *how* can I impelment them myself. with all this jargon, I still don't know where to start coding a goodness-of-fit experiment, whereas Severin's link is entirely instructive with code included

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to instead working in **R**, `JSUparameters` is an **R** package that will do exactly what you need; it will estimate the parameters of the best-fitting Johnson $S_U$ distribution for a given dataset.

The package can be downloaded from CRAN: https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=JSUparameters

You can also view an example of it in use from its GitHub repository: https://github.com/cjclarke98/JSUparameters

Finally, you can read a short blog post about the pacakge at: https://cjclarke.weebly.com/blog